# Chess problem: Make a crossword in 3 moves

Tags: chess, crosswords, checkerboard

> A **crossword position** is a legal chess position with the following property: The board can be thought of as a crossword grid where the pieces on board work as clues. Each type of piece is a clue for their own name (`KING`, `QUEEN`, `ROOK`, `BISHOP`, `KNIGHT` or `PAWN`). That is, you can fill out the empty squares with letters corresponding to the pieces' names.
>
> You do not need to be able to fill *every* square of the board – only all stretches of two or more letters directly to the right or below a piece. If a word can fit both down and across from the same clue, both have to be filled.
>
> [image]
>
> For example, the above is a simple crossword position. Note that neither of the bishops needs to clue the word `BISHOP` because no word of at least 2 letters fits below or to the right of them.

## The puzzle

> In the following position, white to move (and black to help), reach a crossword position on white's third move.
>
> [image]

Comment: is black being 'friendly'?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yeah, both players co-operate to make the position happen.

Comment: crossword tag maybe?

Comment: do we need to fill partial names?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No partials, all filled-in words need to fit in the grid.

Comment: And if there's room to the right of and below a piece, we'll have to fill in the answer both ways, no?

Comment: @MOehm Yeah, if a word can fit both down and across from the same clue, both have to be filled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After

> ```
>  1. Rh3  bxa1=N
>  2. Qxb7 Kxe5
>  3. Qh1
> ```

the board looks like this:

> [image]

Comment: how did you move your black knight to A1?

Comment: Didn't: promoted a new one and captured the old.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be solved before the last queen move? (Assuming we ignore that the puzzle requies 3 white moves and that we just want a crossword position)

Comment: @BrainStone Well, no, for a couple of reasons. Firstly, the word "Queen" wouldn't fit if the queen were at b7, and even if white played Qa7 as the final move to fix that, the empty space at the bottom row would be too long for the word "Knight".

Comment: From my understanding of the puzzle description both would be fine. @jafe can we maybe get a little clarification on it? Because from what I understand the words don’t have to be spelled out completely (if they can’t be) (otherwise the two gap rule hardly makes sense) and it’s also never said that there can’t be any blank spaces left. Unless I’m missing something.